# Getting scipy working with Pyjamas

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyjamas

I am trying to get scipy working with pyjamas. I have a python script that I am trying to convert to javascipt:

```
import scipy

print scipy.zeros(2)
```

However when I load it up in a browser it says this:

```
ImportError: No module named scipy, scipy in context None
```

I found out that I could get pyjs to translate scipy by copying scipy directly to my project folder. When I build my project it translates it but now I get the following error in my browers:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy.show_config, numpy.show_config in context scipy
```

I tried copying numpy directly to the project folder but it doesn't work. Running the python script gives an error saying numpy cannot be imported from the source directory. I looked into getting around this but it keeps going deeper and deeper into the rabbit hole.

My questions then: Is there a way to use scipy in pajamas without having to write a custom module myself? Is it even possible to translate imported modules/packages?

Comment: See [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyjamas-dev/0lr7ox1O9jE) on the pyjamas mailing list.  Numpy is written in C, and Pyjamas can't translate C to javascript.